# Android Google map - fallback if destination direction route not found

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location

I found there are few ways to open the map route by latitude and longitude:

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + destLat + "," + destLong + " (" + safeURLString + ")"; //first way
//String uri = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + destLat + "," + destLong; //second way
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startChildActivity(intent);
}
```

The problem is sometime the first way able to find the route, or sometime only second way able to mark the destination when no route.

Is it possible to check if route not found then fallback/callback to try the second url OR at least mark the destination ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpUrlConnection` and [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) to test route existence:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=<originLat>,<originLon>&destination=<destLat>,<destLon>&key=<YOUR_DIRECTIONS_API_KEY>
```

and if `HttpUrlConnection` response like:

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [ {}, {} ],
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

then the route not exists and you should use your second way to mark the destination when no route. Otherwise, when `HttpUrlConnection` response like

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [

   <lines of response here> 
   ...

   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
...
```

the route exists and you can use first way to find the route. So use [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) via `HttpUrlConnection` and check `"status"` tag: if `"status" : "OK"` - route exists.